# How to submit Nepali date in MySQL DB using Spring MVC?

Tags: java, mysql, date, spring-mvc, calendar

I’m working on a project with Spring MVC (Java) and MySQL database. When I submit Nepali date from page, e.g., 31-04-2079 from Nepali calender .., it automatically converts to 01-05-2079 and saves in MySQL database. Can you please suggest what to do so that I save as it is in the database.

I applied `sql_mode = allow_invalid_date` in MySQL and AM able to insert 31-04-2079.. but not from Spring MVC... I also learnt that when i convert string 31-04-2079 to date from `SimpleDateFormat` ... it rollS over to 01-05-2079. Please guide.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. For Gregorian dates you would use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). For Nepali dates, can you find a library that handles them? I don’t know of one, sorry.

Comment: There seem to be a couple of shots on GitHub. [This one](https://github.com/topics/nepali-calendar) is just one of them, not the only one. Search.